# Python3 Not getting full text on webpage

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I have a webpage from which I want to retrive the email in the middle:

`url = 'https://www.westminster.ac.uk/about-us/our-people/directory/ramachandran-natasha-1'`

I have tried using BeautifoulSoup with requests and urllib and neither works because the email is not included when I `print(page_source)`.

```
page = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
page_source = page.text
```

and

```
page = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
infile = urllib.request.urlopen(page).read()
page_source = infile.decode('ISO-8859-1')
```

I have tried with and without the headers. Also, if I do this using selenium with `driver.get(url)` then it works. But I can't use selenium because it's too slow.

I have seen several other similar threads and they suggested the solutions above, but they don't work for me.

Is there a fast way that I can retrieve the email on that page?

Comment: The email you wish to grab is a dynamic one. Try using selenium.

Comment: Im stating in the question that I don't want to use selenium. Thanks selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url="https://www.westminster.ac.uk/about-us/our-people/directory/ramachandran-natasha-1"
page_data=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page_data.content,"html.parser")

email_id=[]

for job_tag in soup.find_all("div",class_="masthead-profile__result-set"):
    email=job_tag.find("div",class_="masthead-profile__result-value--email email")
    
    email_id.append(email)
```

**this would have worked you see but the email is protected by the website if you would just print the job_tag in the above question you can see that clearly**

Comment: So is there another way to get it?

Comment: i am not sure ...but i think no 
some websites keep some  data protected so that people dont scrape it